# How to point all subdomains to index.php

Tags: apache, .htaccess, vhosts

I'm trying to host a site on which user profile pages come with unique subdomains, such as username.sitename.com. I would like an Apache/VirtualHost solution for pointing *.sitename.com to sitename.com/index.php, where I could assort, which subdomain comes with a profile page and which would show 404 error.

Please help me setting up the .htaccess

Comment: This cannot be done with a .htaccess file.

Comment: Catchall DNS record or what now?

Answer (score 2):

You need only a correct VirtualHost setup.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName example.com 
  ServerAlias *.example.com

  [...] 

</VirtualHost>
```

As the index.php is in the DirectoryIndex it is called automatically, regardless which domain is called. Do dynamically react you have acces to the requested host trough the `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` variable.

Answer (score 0):

It's best to do this with a 301 redirect at the server level in the httpd.conf file (or an included config file). Rather than creating a VirtualHost and making the server answer and filter with an .htaccess file for each domain, you can setup the redirect in the VirtualHost itself.

You can do this with [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html)

```
<VirtualHost *>
  ServerName subdomain.example.com
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http://example.com/index.php [L,R=301]
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *>
  ServerName subdomain2.example.com
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http://example.com/404.php [L,R=301]
</VirtualHost>
```

or if you're running [mod_alias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html) you can use this:

```
<VirtualHost *>
  ServerName subdomain.example.com
  Redirect 301 / http://example.com/index.php
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *>
  ServerName subdomain2.example.com
  Redirect 301 / http://example.com/404.php
</VirtualHost>
```