# Laravel: Wildcard Subdomain Routing not working

Tags: php, laravel

So i'm making a web app using Laravel framework where user can create their own personalized profile page. I want to use sub domain as a user profile page but it is not working.

I'm using this in my routes file:

```
Route::domain('{account}.portfolioof.me')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/',[
        'as' => 'user.portfolio',
        'uses' => 'PortfolioController@getPortfolio'
    ]);
});
```

But the problem is that the index page shows the index of my main website and not the user profile. but if i do Route::get('/somethingelse'), it works and displays the intended content. I want the index page to be user profile and not my main website index.

This is my apache-vhost config for this site

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp2/htdocs/portfolioof.me/public"
    ServerName portfolioof.me
    ServerAlias *.portfolioof.me
</VirtualHost>
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: May this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16259981/how-to-point-all-subdomains-to-index-php) will help you.

Comment: Please edit out of your question the solving part, and make it an answer so your question won't appear unsolved anymore.

Comment: I removed SOLVED from the title. Accepting an answer automatically marks it as being solved. Either post your own answer or delete the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT: I solved this by explicitly defining my main domain and my subdomain in the routes file.** For example if i had

```
Route::domain('{account}.portfolioof.me')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/',[
        'as' => 'user.portfolio',
        'uses' => 'PortfolioController@getPortfolio'
    ]);
});
```

Then i need to do the same with my main domain and put all the requests through my main domain group so it would look something like this

```
Route::domain('portfolioof.me')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/',[
        'as' => 'main.index',
        'uses' => 'SiteController@getIndex'
    ]);
});
```